# unbricking Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite that can not get into Download mode

Tags: download-mode, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-6

While installing LineageOS on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite, I have ended up with a blue screen that says "`An error has occurred while updating the device software.`" There is also a text in red in the top corner that says: "`VOLTAGE Level [2934]`" While looking online, it appears to me that I am supposed to use `odin` (or `jodin3` for me, a linux user) and then flash the device firmware. However all these instructions appear to be in the Download mode, which I can not seem to be able to get to.

The bootloader is unlocked but the tablet is not rooted.

I can not figure out how to get into `Download` mode on this device. I have `fastboot` and `heimdall` installed, as well as `adb` however the problem is that none of these are able to get the device into download mode.

In my `/var/log/messages/` I get:

```
Feb 12 09:42:04 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 09:42:09 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Feb 12 09:42:25 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Feb 12 09:42:25 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 09:42:25 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Feb 12 09:42:25 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Feb 12 09:42:25 localhost kernel: usb 3-2-port3: attempt power cycle
Feb 12 09:42:26 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 09:42:26 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb 12 09:42:26 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb 12 09:42:26 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: device not accepting address 99, error -71
Feb 12 09:42:26 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 100 using xhci_hcd
Feb 12 09:42:26 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb 12 09:42:27 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb 12 09:42:27 localhost kernel: usb 3-2.3: device not accepting address 100, error -71
Feb 12 09:42:27 localhost kernel: usb 3-2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Any suggestions? THanks again in advance, for any and all help!

Comment: What about the hardware key combinations while booting like Volume Up + Power or Volume Up + Volume Down?

Comment: `Volune Up + Power` or `Volume Up + Down` (it is only one button with areas for up and down)  do nothing, but `Volume Down + Power` makes the screen go blank before coming back with the blue screen (there is however a flicker for one time when it comes back).

Comment: I do not quite understand also what that `VOLTAGE Level [2934]` indicates on the top left  of the screen.